# vscode: How to reference types from a node_module library

Tags: typescript, react-native, intellisense, node-modules

I have installed a npm module (`react-native-mobx`) that ships with its types. This is the files from the node_modules directory:

[image]

Pay attention to the highlighted `mobx.d.ts` file which contains the types. I have typescript 2.2.2 installed. And as I now, types are now contained in the `@types` folder, inside the node_modules. In this case, how do I reference this library in my code and have normal intellisence? Should I create a folder '`react-native-mobx`' inside `@types`and copy the mobx.d.ts in there and change its name to index.d.ts?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: should work "out of the box" as far as I know.

You can run 'tsc' manually with the flag ' --traceResolution' and you will see that typescript searches for the types in the `node_modules/react-native-mobx` before it searches in the `node_modules/@types/react-native-mobx` folder.

Comment: Thanks pf the answer. This is the answer I got running 'tsc --traceResolution' :
File 'C:/.../node_modules/react-native-mobx/index.d.ts' does not exist.

Comment: Looks like tsc expects an index.d.ts on the root of the library

Answer (score 0):

This should just be working for you.  What version of `mobx` are you using?

In `mobx@3.1.5` the `node_modules/mobx/package.json` specifies `"typings": "lib/mobx.d.ts"` which the TypeScript `tsc` compiler will inspect to find the typings.

If `package.json` doesn't specify a `typings` or `types` value, then it will default to looking for `index.d.ts`, see the docs for more specific information about how they're resolved: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

Perhaps you're on an older version of `mobx` that didn't have a proper `package.json` with `typings` specified

Answer (score 0):

@Alex, thanks for the answer. And yes the `package.json` specifies `typings": "lib/mobx.d.ts`. The thing is: this file definition is not located on the root of the library but inside a sub directory. This is the folder structure inside the project node_modules folder:

```
 /react-native-mobx
    -index.js
    -package.json
    -readme.md
    ...
    /node_modules
         /mobx
            -package.json <-- "typings: lib/mobx.d.ts"
            /lib
               - mob.d.ts
```

When I run `tsc --traceResolution`, I can see that typescript is indeed parsing this inner folder. But it reports that package.json does not contains typings, very weird...

**update**
As a work around I copied **mobx.d.ts** from its inner folder into the root folder and I changed its name to `index.d.ts`. Now typescript picks up the types. But this is a very ugly work-around since I am messing up with files inside the node_modules folder.